# apt update seems broken

Tags: apt, updates

On one of our servers, `apt update` gives weird errors:

```
me@mimer:/etc/apt$ sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release
  503  Cache storage error - No such file or directory
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release
  503  Cache storage error - No such file or directory
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Err:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release
  503  Cache storage error - No such file or directory
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/costamagnagianfranco/borgbackup/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial Release
  503  Cache storage error - No such file or directory
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/costamagnagianfranco/borgbackup/ubuntu xenial Release
  503  Cache storage error - No such file or directory
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/costamagnagianfranco/borgbackup/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

One difference to the machine below that for some reason `mimer` is also looking for Release, but I can't figure out why or where that's configured.

```
me@mimer:/etc/apt$ grep -R Release .
me@mimer:/etc/apt$
```

Nothing?

In the meantime, on another machine it works just fine:

```
me@freja:/etc/apt$ sudo apt update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                   
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                               
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]                                                                                 
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                                  
Ign:7 http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ InRelease                                                                        
Hit:8 http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ Release
Hit:9 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:10 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x xenial InRelease
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [1120 kB]
Fetched 1338 kB in 1s (789 kB/s)                              
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
...
```

Some random `greps` and stuff I've tried:

`mimer` does have network and the files seem to be there?

```
me@mimer:/etc/apt$ curl -s http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/Release | head
Origin: Ubuntu
Label: Ubuntu
Suite: xenial
Version: 16.04
Codename: xenial
Date: Thu, 21 Apr 2016 23:23:46 UTC
Architectures: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el s390x
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Description: Ubuntu Xenial 16.04
MD5Sum:
```

`sources.list` from `mimer`:

```
me@mimer:/etc/apt$ cat sources.list
#
#  /etc/apt/sources.list
#


#
# trusty
#
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe
```

Both machines are running 16.04.

```
me@mimer:/etc/apt$ lsb_release -id
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
```

Now to something weird, if I change the `sources.list` to add `[trusted=yes]` it seems to work. Is there some key or certificate or something that can expire?

I've tried `apt clean`, removing the `apt` lock file etc.

Please help, I've been bashing my head against this all day and would be really happy to move on to what I was planning on doing today... :) If you want output from anything just let me know.

Comment: Are you using something like `apt-cacher` on this server?

Comment: @steeldriver I wasn't, but your comment made me think that maybe there was a proxy configured. There was, and when I removed that `apt.conf.d/00proxy` file it now works. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turned out that there was an apt proxy configured on that server (small company, I wear many, many hats etc...) and apparently that proxy wasn't working anymore.

```
me@mimer:/etc/apt/apt.conf.d$ cat 00proxy 
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://1.2.3.4:3142";
```

I moved that file to another directory and then `apt update` now works again. Woo!